# Creating a custom comparer for a complex object of Type T

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tree

I am creating a Tree structure in C# and I have some specific goals:

- When a user of `Tree`creates `new Tree` they are required to pass in
  a type of `ITreeComparer`, the user knows the type of `T` and must
  create the correct Comparer.
- `Tree` class creates all instances of `TreeNode` the caller only adds values of type `T` to the `Tree` class. `TreeNode` is private and a child class of the `Tree` class So I need a way to pass the IComparer to `TreeNode` so I made `ITreeComparer` static.
- I want to use my custom `ITreeComparer`for complex types of 'T' but I would like to have ITReeComparer inherit from IComparer so that a user of Tree is not required not required to pass `ITreeComparer` when the type T is primitives, like double and int.

My questions:

1. I wish there was a way to keep the ITreeComparer in the `Tree` class
   even though `Tree` class handles comparisons of itself. I made the
   `ITreeComparision` property in `TreeNode` static, any better
   solutions than this?
2. I am getting a warning that `TreeNode` **defines '==' or '!=' but
   does not override 'Object.Equals(object o) and
   'Object.GetHasCode'**, why would I use Object.Equals when I want to
   use the `_comparer.Compare(x.Value, y.Value)`, `_comparer` is the
   passed in `ITreeComparer` instance creator of `Tree` must supply.
3. If `ITreeComparer` were to implement `IComparer` would I just check
   if my `_comparer is null` and if is use the `IComparer` default
   Comparison, that way as user of `Tree` does not have to pass in an `ITreeComparison` implmentation?

   ```
   public interface ITreeComparer<in T>
   {
       int Compare(T x, T y);
   }


   public class Tree<T>
   {
    private TreeNode _root = null;
    private ITreeComparer<T> _comparer = null;


   public Tree(ITreeComparer<T> comparer)
   {
       _comparer = comparer;
   }

   public Tree(T value, ITreeComparer<T> comparer)
   {
       _root =  new TreeNode(value,_comparer);
       _comparer = comparer;
   }

   public T Add(T value)
   {
       var newNode = new TreeNode(value, _comparer);
       if (_root == null)
       {
           _root = newNode;
           return _root.Value;
       }
       else
       {
           var startEdgeDirection = EdgeDirection.Left;

           if (_root > newNode) 
               startEdgeDirection = EdgeDirection.Right;

           var parent = FindItemNodeParent(value, _root, startEdgeDirection);
       }

       return value;
   }

   private TreeNode FindItemNodeParent(T value, TreeNode current , EdgeDirection direction)
   {
       throw new NotImplementedException();

       if (_comparer.Compare(current.Value, value) == 0)
           return null;

       if (direction == EdgeDirection.Left)
       {

       }
       else
       {

       }

   }

   private TreeNode Search(T value, TreeNode current, EdgeDirection direction )
   {
       throw new NotImplementedException();

       if (_comparer.Compare(current.Value, value) == 0)
           return null;

       if (direction == EdgeDirection.Left)
       {

       }
       else
       {

       }
   }

   private enum EdgeDirection
   {
       Left,
       Right
   }


   private class TreeNode
   {
       private static ITreeComparer<T> _comparer;
       public TreeNode LeftEdge { get; set; }
       public TreeNode RightEdge { get; set; }
       public T Value { get; set; }

       public TreeNode(ITreeComparer<T> comparer)
       {
           _comparer = comparer;
       }

       public TreeNode(T value, ITreeComparer<T> comparer)
       {
           Value = value;
           _comparer = comparer;
       }

       public static bool operator < (TreeNode x, TreeNode y)
       {
             if (x == null)
               return y == null;
           return _comparer.Compare(x.Value, y.Value) < 0;

       }

       public static bool operator > (TreeNode x, TreeNode y)
       {
             if (x == null)
               return y == null;

           return _comparer.Compare(x.Value, y.Value) > 0;
       }

       public static bool operator == (TreeNode x, TreeNode y)
       {
           if (x == null)
               return y == null;

           return _comparer.Compare(x.Value, y.Value) == 0;
       }

       public static bool operator != (TreeNode x, TreeNode y)
       {
            if (x == null)
               return y == null;

           return _comparer.Compare(x.Value, y.Value)  != 0;
       }
   }
   ```

   }

**UPDATE**

After the advice from the helpful Stackoverflowers I am just using IComparable, I have removed all my overloaded comparison operators from TreeNode and I am setting my private `IComparer<T> _comparer` to `Comparer<T>.Default`. This always works because I added `where T: IComparable', which means a user of Tree will have to implement IComparable on their custom T object, for C# primitives, IComparable already implemented and they will not have to implement IComparable when T is int for example and they will never need to pass in an IComparer because the must always implement IComparable for their type T.

```
    public partial class Tree<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    private TreeNode _root = null;
    private IComparer<T> _comparer = null;


    public Tree()
    {
        _comparer = Comparer<T>.Default;
    }

    public Tree(T value)
    {
        _root = new TreeNode(value);
        _comparer = Comparer<T>.Default;
    }

    public T Add(T value)
    {
        var newNode = new TreeNode(value);
        if (_root == null)
        {
            _root = newNode;
            return _root.Value;
        }

        var startEdgeDirection = EdgeDirection.Left;

        if (_comparer.Compare(_root.Value, value) > 0)
            startEdgeDirection = EdgeDirection.Right;

        var parent = FindItemNodeParent(value, _root, startEdgeDirection);

        if (parent != null)
        {
            if (_comparer.Compare(parent.Value, value) > 0)
            {
                parent.RightDescendant = newNode;
            }
            else
            {
                parent.LeftDescendant = newNode;
            }
        }


        return value;
    }

    private TreeNode FindItemNodeParent(T value, TreeNode current, EdgeDirection direction)
    {
        if (_comparer.Compare(current.Value, value) == 0)
            return null;

        if (direction == EdgeDirection.Left)
        {
            if (current.LeftDescendant == null)
                return current;

            if (_comparer.Compare(current.LeftDescendant.Value, value) > 0)
            {
                FindItemNodeParent(value, current.LeftDescendant, EdgeDirection.Right);
            }
            else
            {
                FindItemNodeParent(value, current.LeftDescendant, EdgeDirection.Left);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (current.RightDescendant == null)
                return current;

            if (_comparer.Compare(current.RightDescendant.Value, value) > 0)
            {
                FindItemNodeParent(value, current.RightDescendant, EdgeDirection.Right);
            }
            else
            {
                FindItemNodeParent(value, current.RightDescendant, EdgeDirection.Left);
            }

        }

        return null;

    }

    private TreeNode Search(T value, TreeNode current, EdgeDirection direction)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();

        if (_comparer.Compare(current.Value, value) == 0)
            return null;

        if (direction == EdgeDirection.Left)
        {

        }
        else
        {

        }
    }

    private enum EdgeDirection
    {
        Left,
        Right
    }

}

 public partial class Tree<T>
{
    private class TreeNode
    {
        public TreeNode LeftDescendant { get; set; }
        public TreeNode RightDescendant { get; set; }
        public T Value { get; set; }

        public TreeNode(T value)
        {
            Value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Question 1: you can make `Tree` a partial class, which allows you to split it across multiple files. Then `TreeNode` can be an inner class but in a different file.

Comment: Thanks, I removed that part from my question because I saw it as off topic from my question heading, you answer worked though, thanks again

Comment: Do you really need to implement operators on TreeNode if it's private anyway? You could just use the comparer in the outer class (which you seem to be doing in a few places).

Comment: I don't implement operators on the outer class. TreeNode is what stores value of type T, the Tree itself is a container for TreeNodes

Comment: But yes, I guess the operator overloads and comparisons could live in the outer class Tree, only thing weird about that to me is that a comparsion overload would compare treeNodex.Value to treeNodey.Value...

Comment: I don't understand the point of the `ITreeComparer` interface at all. How is it different from `IComparer`? Why can't the client code just pass an `IComparer` implementation? Why do you need a whole new interface? What does `ITreeComparer.Compare()` do that the `IComparer.Compare()` method does not?

Comment: Nothing yet, and I want ITreeComparer to inherit from IComparer but I just want ITreeComparer for my code, just Sandboxing something

Comment: You'd better revisit your design. Your are mixing IComparer with IComparable concepts. The user passed comparer cannot be static member of a node, thus you cannot define node static operators.

Comment: So my ITreeComparer would be a part of every instance of TreeNode, not a big deal but for a very large dataset no reason to have that addition overhead, I will have to move comparison operations to the outer class Tree

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment above, I don't understand why you have the interface `ITreeComparer`. It seems to me that it's exactly the same as `IComparer`, and so you could just use `IComparer` instead.

That said…

> 1. I wish there was a way to keep the ITreeComparer in the Tree class even though Tree class handles comparisons of itself. I made the ITreeComparision property in TreeNode static, any better solutions than this?

I agree making it `static` is a bad idea. One obvious problem is that it means you are limited to only a single kind of `Tree<T>` in a process (i.e. for any given `T`, there can only ever be one kind of comparison). This means, for example, that if you have a class with properties `Name` and `Id`, you can only have trees that order by `Name`, or trees that order by `Id`, but not both kinds of trees a the same time.

Indeed, with this field `static` in the `TreeNode<T>` class, there's no point in it being an instance field in `Tree<T>`, since all `Tree<T>` objects are going to use the same `TreeNode<T>` type.

It seems to me that the only reason you even expose the `ITreeComparer` to the `TreeNode` is for the purpose of allowing the overloaded comparison operators. If you must have those operators, I would go ahead and make the `_comparer` field non-static in `TreeNode<T>`, or even just change it to a reference to the parent `Tree<T>` object (and then it can get the `_comparer` from the parent).

But really, I don't feel that the comparison operators help much. You might as well just call `_comparer` directly in the `Tree<T>` class and not bother having `TreeNode<T>` even know how to compare itself.

> 2. I am getting a warning that TreeNode defines '==' or '!=' but does not override 'Object.Equals(object o) and 'Object.GetHasCode', why would I use Object.Equals when I want to use the _comparer.Compare(x.Value, y.Value), _comparer is the passed in ITreeComparer instance creator of Tree must supply.

For better or worse, there are several different ways for objects to compare themselves in C#. Any time these ways are not implemented identically, you are setting yourself up for some real head-scratcher bugs.

So, when you overload equality-related operators `==` and `!=`, but not the `Equals()` method, you get a warning. Likewise, implementing custom equality relationships without fixing `GetHashCode()` to properly reflect those equality relationships is a good way to get very-hard-to-fix bugs.

It's really important, if you start implementing equality operations within a type itself, to make sure you go through and make consistent *all* equality-related operations in that type.

> 3. If ITreeComparer were to implement IComparer would I just check if my _comparer is null and if is use the IComparer default Comparison, that way as user of Tree does not have to pass in an ITreeComparison implmentation?

As I mentioned, I think you should just drop `ITreeComparer` altogether. There's no actual "sandboxing" going on…indeed, the user could make a single class implement both interfaces if they wanted, using the exact same method within the interface. Forcing a user to implement a custom interface when a built-in one would suffice just makes things more annoying for them.

As long as I'm writing, I'll agree that [the non-answer provided by](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33359742) [ipavlu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4784579/ipavlu) does offer some useful observations. In particular, your handling of nulls is all wrong. The other post notes some of the problems. Another problem is if `x` and `y` are both null, your comparison operators both return `true`. I.e. according to the code, `x` and `y` are both simultaneously greater than and less than each other, if they are both null.

Fortunately, there's really no apparent reason that the comparisons should need to handle nulls at all. The original implementation (provided by the user) is by convention required to accommodate nulls already. Your own code should not need to check for them. Furthermore, there's no apparent cause for null values to appear in the tree at all. A null node reference doesn't make much sense: any time you reach a null in your tree, that's where you're going to store a node; there's no need to decide whether the new node goes to the left or to the right of that null…it goes right where the null is at that time!

Comment: Awesome answer, learning, I appreciate it. So I will remove ITreeComparer and just allow the user of Tree to pass in an implementation of IComparer. They do not even need to pass an I Comparer in for types string,int,double, primitve types right? I can just check if my private _comparer is null and it is I can call Comparer<T>.Default? I am still reading up on IComparer

Comment: @BrianOgden: yes, you can always use `Comparer<T>.Default` if the client code passes `null`. You can even do this when `T` is not a built-in primitive, as long as the type itself implements `IComparable`.

Comment: There wouldn't be much point to me implementing IComparable for Type T I guess, I wouldn't know what T is. But if I did, like so public partial class Tree<T> where T : IComparable<T>. I see I have no build errors in Tree, even though I have not implemented the Comparable method anywhere in Tree

Comment: @BrianOgden: _"I wouldn't know what T is"_ -- no, you wouldn't. But that's fine. Only the type `T` itself can implement `IComparable` anyway. I.e. it's not your code that would implement...it's the code that calls your code that would. (You might be the author of that too, later on, but that's you wearing a different hat :) ).

Comment: I see, so by adding "where T: IComparable<T>" to my class Tree<T> I am enforcing users of Tree<T> to implement IComparable, yes?

Comment: I added my improved code by the way in my question, thanks for all the help @Peter Duniho, much obliged

Comment: @BrianOgden: Happy to help, of course. _"I am enforcing users of Tree<T> to implement IComparable"_ -- yes, that's true. However, you may not want to require that in all cases, if you also are providing the option for them to provide `IComparer<T>`. One option might be, instead of putting a generic constraint, just check in the constructor whether `T is IComparable` and throw an exception if not, but do that only if the caller does not provide an `IComparer<T>`.

Comment: Got it! Yes I could implement a SortList<T> style Comparison setup where you can passin IComparer if you want, it's interesting, I would think SortedList<T> would have  to have T inherit from IComparable to sort correctly but it doesn't: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/sortedlist.cs

Answer (score 1):

There is big problem in your code:

```
public static bool operator == (TreeNode x, TreeNode y)
{
    if (x == null) return y == null;

    return _comparer.Compare(x.Value, y.Value) == 0;
}
```

x is TreeNode and y is TreeNode, so:

```
      if (x == null) return y == null;
```

**x == null** would end up calling operator== method, so the method is calling itself.

You have to do this:

```
(object)x == null,
```

As long as you use the same type, the operator== will call itself.
For this to make it clean is here object.ReferenceEquals.

**Also, did you noted, that your code is not null safe?**
What it x != null and y == null?
Then y.Value will throw exception in line:

```
    return _comparer.Compare(x.Value, y.Value) == 0;
```

Try something like this instead:

```
public static bool operator == (TreeNode x, TreeNode y)
{
    var x_null = object.ReferenceEquals(x,null);
    var y_null = object.ReferenceEquals(y,null);
    if (x_null && y_null) return true;
    if (x_null || y_null) return false;

    //now is x.Value, y.Value is safe to call
    return _comparer.Compare(x.Value, y.Value) == 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, mean by if (x -- null) return y == null; would "try to call itself? x is an instance of a TreeNde, yes?

Comment: Yes, x,y are instances on TreeNodes, **x == null** would be calling operator== method, so the method is calling itself...

Comment: These are all true statements, but this post fails to answer any of the questions the OP actually had.

Comment: @PeterDuniho This is the **StackOveflow site**, what can be more rightful than an answer to an unexpressed (implicit) question about the cause of the stack overflow exception? ROFL